# Set Height of custom Table View cell

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have created custom tableview cell in `UITableView` with style grouped.
My dustom tableview cell has 3 label. 
I want to display it as follow:

```
    [first label]
    [Second label]
    [Third Label]
```

Where first label and second label can have text of 1 or 2 lines and Third label has text of single line.

How can I resize label in custom cell, so That if label1 has one line of text then label 2 starts imeediatly after it rather than providing space for 2 lines.

And one more thing using `[firstlabe sizeToFit]` add ... end of first line if firstlabel has text that can fit in single line.
Since I have added support for ios5 I can not use AutoLayout.

Comment: One option is to use a custom `UITableViewCell` class and layout the labels in the `layoutSubview` method.

Comment: How should I resize height of UItableViewCell?

Comment: You must use the `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` delegate method.

Comment: I have tried to use heightForRowAtInedxPath: method but it does not work for me.